# Are there words to differentiate two instances of the same season in a year?

Tags: seasons

I'm in the northern hemisphere. I was organizing some photo albums online and I realized that the album name "Winter 2012" could be considered ambiguous. Are these photos from the first few months of 2012 or the last 10 days (or so) of 2012? Is there a word that means the first instance or second instance of a season in a given year? I eventually settled on "Winter Early 2012" as the photos were taken in January. But I'm wondering if a fancier term exists. I suppose that when talking about time periods on the scale of seasons, "Winter 2013" is perfectly acceptable for something that happened on December 23rd, 2012, but I don't like the idea of labeling my photos with the wrong year.

Comment: The fancier term is *winter, 2013-2014*.

Comment: Seasons overlap calendar year -- decide between season and year. It doesn't sound like a good idea to me to mix the two.

Answer (score 6):

Have you considered **Winter 2012/13**, since this avoids any ambiguity?

Comment: Yeah, that's better than mine. Not sure why I didn't think of that. There are plenty of similar examples, like the 2012-2013 school year, or the 97-98 NHL season.

Comment: Although, in those examples the time is more evenly balanced between the two years. Seems strange to call it Winter 2012/13 when we're only talking a few days in 2012, but it does seem to be used a fair amount.

Comment: @regularmike I agree the time isn't evenly distributed, but it's the span, not the distribution of it, that is the issue.

Comment: yeah, I agree. I've warmed up to it. Just makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would say **Jan 2012** and **Dec 2012**, respectively, and won't care about it that much. As long as you can make it out yourself later, it should be fine. If you worry so much about others, you should also include the time zone, since Jan 2012 in China, for example, was Jan 2013 for US.

Comment: I didn't want to use months because I already have a lot of albums doing it by season. Do you mean December 2012 in China? I can live with any timezone issues. Just going by the "date taken" property of the file.

Comment: No, I actually meant Jan 2012 in China, since the new year is in February there, so when we are already in Jan 2015, they will still be in Jan 2014, their 2015 will start with Feb.

Comment: The official calendar in China is the Western calendar, though. My Flickr account isn't a traditional Chinese Flickr account.